# Numerical Methods for Discontinuous or Indifferentiable Functions

Tags: numerical-methods

The title says it all; by now, I have learned quite a few numerical methods for finding the roots of a function that is differentiable. However, I haven't heard of any strategy or method analogous for functions that are either discontinuous or indifferentiable. Are there any well known theories or works surrounding this topic?

Comment: Bisection works for continuous functions.

Comment: Do you know any nondifferentiable functions whose zeros are interesting? If yes, then this would be a valuable addition to your question.